# Adding multiple ranges for different target values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Im trying to add 2 different range and target value criteria. If the values are out or specified target value ranges, an email will be sent. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim xRg As Range, rng As Range

'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("K3050:K4000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0.534 Or Target.Value < 0.519 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    
  Set rng = Intersect(Range("L3050:L4000"), Target)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0.003 Or Target.Value < 0.003 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "There is an out of spec value on 302-0092. Please confirm."
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "EMAIL HERE"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Out of spec value on 302-0092"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The first range of K3050:K4000 works and is able to generate an email, but I can't get the second range to work.

Comment: The problem is `If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` ... you `Exit Sub` before getting to check against `L3050:L4000`.

Comment: Change `If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` to `If Not xRg Is Nothing Then` and then add `End If` after each `End If`.

Comment: @BigBen Removed `Exit Sub` and added the `End If` statements. Now I am getting 2 emails generated...

Comment: Did you also add the `Not`? You should have `If Not xRg Is Nothing Then` and `If Not rng Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @BigBen Forgot to add that. Everything Works! Thanks for the help, you're awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring comments to an answer:

The problem is `If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, since you `Exit Sub` before checking if `Target` intersects the second range, `L3050:L4000`.

Flip the logic; change:

```
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

to

```
If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
...
End If
```

and similarly (though not needed) for `rng`.